# Solving $\frac{x}{w} \geq 1 - 0.5^{1/(y-1)}$ for $y$. Messed up sign somewhere?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> I want to solve the following equation in terms of $y$:

> $$\frac{x}{w} \geq 1 - 0.5^{1/(y-1)}$$

When I get done, it should look like

$$y \geq \frac{\ln(0.5)+\ln(1-x/w)}{\ln(1-x/w)}$$

Here's what I've done.

$$0.5^{1/(y-1)} \geq 1 - \frac{x}{w}$$

$$\frac{1}{y-1} \geq \log_{0.5}(1-\frac{x}{w})$$

$$ 1 \geq \log_{0.5}(1-\frac{x}{w})(1-y)$$
$$y\log_{0.5}(1-\frac{x}{w}) \geq  \log_{0.5}(1-\frac{x}{w}) - 1$$
$$y \geq  \frac{\log_{0.5}(1-\frac{x}{w}) - 1}{\log_{0.5}(1-\frac{x}{w})}$$

$$y \geq  1 - \frac{1}{\log_{0.5}(1-\frac{x}{w})}$$

$$y \geq 1 - \frac{\ln(0.5)}{\ln(1-\frac{x}{w})} $$

$$y \geq \frac{\ln(1-\frac{x}{w})-\ln(0.5)}{\ln(1-\frac{x}{w})}$$

Which is very close but somewhere I think I messed up the signs... Some help finding where I'm going wrong would be awesome.

Comment: Can you say more about $y$? Is $y>1$ or $y<1$?

Comment: It is greater than 1! Sorry that was specified I’m the problem and I forgot to include it

Comment: Do you know if it is mentioned that $x/w<1$? It doesn't matter if not, but it was just to know.

Comment: I edited my answer, let me know if it helps you and if you have any question.

Comment: @Axel. In the context of the problem, X can be any values greater than 0 and W is wealth. So $x/w$ can probably be any value greater than 0 as well. It’s an Econ question exploring properties of power utility and whether or not it seems reasonable in certain contexts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\log_{1/2}$ is a decreasing function on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$ so the second inequality is false!

I suggest you to write $0.5^{1/(y-1)} $ as $e^{\ln(0.5)/(y-1)}$.

Here is what I have:

$$ \dfrac{x}{w} \geq 1-(1/2)^{1/(y-1)}$$

$$ e^{\ln(1/2)/(y-1)} \geq 1 - \dfrac{x}{w}$$

From there I assume $x/w <1$ else the inequality holds at least for all $y>1$.

$$ \dfrac{\ln{(1/2)}}{y-1} \geq \ln{\left(1-\dfrac{x}{w}\right)}$$

$$ \ln{(1/2)} \geq (y-1) \ln{\left(1-\dfrac{x}{w}\right)}$$

$$y \ln{\left(1-\dfrac{x}{w}\right)}\leq \ln(1/2)+\ln\left(1-\dfrac{x}{w} \right) $$

Then if we suppose $x/w>0$ it means $\ln(1-x/w)<0$ so we have:

$$ y \geq \dfrac{\ln(1/2) + \ln\left(1-\dfrac{x}{w}\right)}{\ln\left(1-\dfrac{x}{w}\right)} $$